# How can I use Blob detection to Isolate region in an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to measure area of land in an aerial view image, so I was adviced to first use blob detection to Isolate region and threshold the  image. Here is what I have done, but I am not sure if this is correct.

```
img = cv2.imread('landarea.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)  
# Set up the detector with default parameters.  
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()  

# Detecting blobs.  
keypoints = detector.detect(img) 

# Draw detected blobs as red circles.  
# cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size 

im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 
                                                   255),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)  
# Show keypoints  
print(im_with_keypoints.size)

# plt.show()
cv2.imshow("Blob",im_with_keypoints )
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
 # Convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im_with_keypoints, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#Threshold the image
ret3,th3 = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

titles = ["Otsu's Thresholding"]
images = [th3]

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
for i in range(1):
    plt.subplot(1,1,i+1), plt.imshow(images[i], 'gray')
    plt.title(titles[i])
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])

plt.show()
```

[Image Link](https://github.com/okoliechykwuka/models/blob/master/landarea.jpg)

In summary this is what I am trying to achieve

**Task : Land Area Measurement:**

**I am current working on getting the Area, Width and Height Measurement of a Land from aerial Mapping Images. Steps taken to achieve this are listed below:**

1. I was advice that it's better to write a Python code from scratch to do my Image processing.
2. Also from SO, I was advice to use a blob detector to isolates regions, threshold my image and count the number of white pixels. Then I can calibrate the dimensions of the image with ground truth dimensions.
   I have been able to detect blobs, threshold the image and I have also been able to get the count of white pixels. My major challenge is on the last two steps and how to get the measurement from this steps.
   Also a friend said that normally the shape of any photo could be square, rectangle, etc. So the area might not vary if I measure area with photos.

Comment: Post a link to your input image.

Comment: @fmw42 I just added a link to the image [Image Link](https://github.com/okoliechykwuka/models/blob/master/landarea.jpg)

Comment: I do not think blob detection is going to work well. You would need to threshold the image in some way to separate the land area from everything else. From what part of the image do you want to get the area?

Comment: @fmw42 from the  the entire image.

Comment: @fmw42 and I also want to compare the area with the ground truth area, which steps would you advise me to take in acheving this...?

Comment: I do not know what is the area you want. Please show on your image or describe. Everything in your image is ground, some has trees.

Comment: @fmw42 I just updated my post for  you to get a better understandig of what I am trying to do. Am unable to post images on `SO` because i don't have up to 10 reputation to do so

Comment: You can post to any free image hosting company and put the URL here. Without an image showing what you want to locate, it is hard for anyone to understand or recommend anything. Also show the results of your processing and explain why it is not working the way you want.

Comment: There is no edge detection in your code. So it if that is what you need, you have not done that.

Comment: @fmw42 I posted a similar question few weeks back on stack overflow and you advice I use a blob detection [Here is the Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190681/i-am-trying-to-measure-land-plot-area-using-opencv-in-python)

Comment: I suspect you'll get better results if you are able to do a *"Supervised Classification"*  https://www.ukessays.com/essays/engineering/supervised-image-classification-9746.php

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for your suggestion.. Let me go through the link to understand better.

Comment: @MarkSetchell If I decide to approach the task with a **Supervised classifier**, knowing too well that all I need from the algorithm or model is an area measurement of the land. I would be able to relate the output of the classifier to the area measurement...?

Comment: @MarkSetchell also, I see the different classes i intend classifiying the image not be my major point of interest, reasons because irrespective of the class type, I still need a similar output from all the classes which an area measurement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I do not think blob detection is going to work well. You would need to threshold the image in some way to separate the land area from everything else. From what part of the image do you want to get the area?

Comment: Just a copy of my comment above.